# How do I mount LZMA filesystem or extract to modify them

Tags: filesystems, compression, firmware, reverse-engineer

I am working on a firmware with binwalk a bunch of LZMA compressed data ...

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
512           0x200           LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 20082112 bytes
3867692       0x3B042C        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 36056 bytes
3877404       0x3B2A1C        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 5011 bytes
3879208       0x3B3128        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 2238 bytes
3880104       0x3B34A8        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 1356 bytes
3880804       0x3B3764        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 1784 bytes
3881448       0x3B39E8        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 1915 bytes
3882124       0x3B3C8C        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 4052 bytes
```

now I unpacked the first partition of LZMA as it was of most size

```
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 20082112 bytes
```

Then I did unlzma -d filename to get it further extracted.. Now when I do a binwalk on the output file I can see the filesystems but how do I further extract them to get the files so I can work with them..

The LZMA binwalk is as follows

```
binwalk -t Lzma1

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
15148890      0xE7275A        eCos RTOS string reference: "ECOS"
15283022      0xE9334E        eCos RTOS string reference: "ECOS"
15298264      0xE96ED8        eCos RTOS string reference: "ECOS"
15298321      0xE96F11        eCos RTOS string reference: "ECOS"
15298392      0xE96F58        eCos RTOS string reference: "ECOS"
15298475      0xE96FAB        eCos RTOS string reference: "ECOS"
16026097      0xF489F1        PARity archive data - Index file
16232606      0xF7B09E        Copyright string: "Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Broadcom Corporation"
16278276      0xF86304        Broadcom 96345 firmware header, header size: 256, firmware version: "IPC6", ~CRC32 header checksum: 0x6C000000, ~CRC32 data checksum: 0x20646973
16278320      0xF86330        Broadcom 96345 firmware header, header size: 256, firmware version: "udes", board id: " tunneled", ~CRC32 header checksum: 0x61636B65, ~CRC32 data checksum: 0x72782075
16278428      0xF8639C        Broadcom 96345 firmware header, header size: 256, firmware version: "s", board id: "DISC", ~CRC32 header checksum: 0x706F6C69, ~CRC32 data checksum: 0x50444953
16280552      0xF86BE8        Broadcom 96345 firmware header, header size: 256, firmware version: "IPD6", ~CRC32 header checksum: 0x20202020, ~CRC32 data checksum: 0x6E656C20
16280596      0xF86C14        Broadcom 96345 firmware header, header size: 256, firmware version: "Pack", board id: "ets", ~CRC32 header checksum: 0x20202020, ~CRC32 data checksum: 0x20706163
16312229      0xF8E7A5        eCos RTOS string reference: "eCosPriority"
16454036      0xFB1194        Copyright string: "Copyright(C) "
16457112      0xFB1D98        Neighborly text, "neighbor_id"
16529360      0xFC37D0        Base64 standard index table
16654554      0xFE20DA        Copyright string: "Copyright(C) %s %s Corporation. All rights reserved."
16799600      0x1005770       Neighborly text, "neighbor timer is failedremote entry in."
16803314      0x10065F2       Neighborly text, "neighbor_proco"
16809387      0x1007DAB       Neighborly text, "neighbor timer is faileddp_handle_txttr_exp "
17146430      0x105A23E       Neighborly text, "neighbor(5)]}ecific sort of devices."
17147925      0x105A815       Neighborly text, "Neighbor_table delete [by_port(1) <port>|by_mac(2) <macaddr>|by_port_and_mac(3) <port> <macaddr>]_port_and_mac(3) <port> <macaddr>]"
17155638      0x105C636       Neighborly text, "Neighbor Info Table --- ------------------ ---------"
17262325      0x10766F5       Neighborly text, "Neighbor Cache mac info error! ge_IP_RTMODIFY mac len error %x"
17313480      0x1082EC8       Neighborly text, "NeighborCacheRouteStatusouteStatus"
17313600      0x1082F40       Neighborly text, "NeighborCacheTableDel_Unresolved_Entry]  ip: %v  send_sec: %d, interval: %d, send_cnt: %d, flag: %d,unresolved_entry->circ_id :%d"
17316037      0x10838C5       Neighborly text, "NeighborCacheEntryByMAC"
17316069      0x10838E5       Neighborly text, "NeighborCacheA3_NDP_Add_NC_Entry fail"
17317381      0x1083E05       Neighborly text, "neighbor_cache ipif [<ipif_name 12> | all ] [static(1) | dynamic(2) |all(3)]c(2) |all(3)]"
17317523      0x1083E93       Neighborly text, "neighbor_cache ipif [<ipif_name 12> | all ] [ipv6address(1) <ipv6addr> | static(2) | dynamic(3) |all(4)] v6addr> | static(2) | dynamic(3) |all(4)] "
17317645      0x1083F0D       Neighborly text, "neighbor_cache ipif [<ipif_name 12> | all][<ipv6addr> |static |dynamic | all]dynamic | all]"
17317789      0x1083F9D       Neighborly text, "neighbor_cache ipif <ipif_name 12> <ipv6addr> <macaddr> to make a static entry into the NDP table."
17317952      0x1084040       Neighborly text, "Neighbor Discover configurations.if_name 12> retrans_time <millisecond 0-4294967295>"
17318170      0x108411A       Neighborly text, "Neighbor Cache Table-----------------------8s"
17318236      0x108415C       Neighborly text, "Neighbor---------------------  ------------------ ------------ -----"
17319142      0x10844E6       Neighborly text, "neighbor_cache ipif <ipif_name 12> <ipv6addr> <macaddr>fig ipv6 nd ns ipif <ipif_name 12> retrans_time <millisecond 0-4294967295>"
17320319      0x108497F       Neighborly text, "Neighbor3"
17467530      0x10A888A       Neighborly text, "Neighbor: the IF ptr is NULL %s gen err: Type = %dIp6AddrIsNeighbor: the address is NULL %s gen err: Type = %d"
17467602      0x10A88D2       Neighborly text, "Neighbor: the address is NULL %s gen err: Type = %dGlobalAddr: index:%x dst:%v plen:%x"
17573580      0x10C26CC       Neighborly text, "Neighbor.js"
17611248      0x10CB9F0       HTML document header
17611256      0x10CB9F8       HTML document footer
17632050      0x10D0B32       Neighborly text, "Neighbor_Settings= [ ']"
17812131      0x10FCAA3       Unix path: /etc/asd/ifcfg.
17870832      0x110AFF0       VxWorks WIND kernel version "2.11"
18599023      0x11BCC6F       eCos RTOS string reference: "eCosPriority=true|false] [DiscardSource=true|false]"
18992012      0x121CB8C       Neighborly text, "neighbor cache not exist!"
18992152      0x121CC18       Neighborly text, "neighbor entry has been existed."
18992293      0x121CCA5       Neighborly text, "neighbor is conflict with FT entrie."
18992447      0x121CD3F       Neighborly text, "neighbors."
18993875      0x121D2D3       Neighborly text, "neighbor"
19010240      0x12212C0       Certificate in DER format (x509 v3), header length: 4, sequence length: 717
19010964      0x1221594       Private key in DER format (PKCS header length: 4, sequence length: 604
19118731      0x123BA8B       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19119607      0x123BDF7       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19120499      0x123C173       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19121391      0x123C4EF       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19122247      0x123C847       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19123107      0x123CBA3       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19123979      0x123CF0B       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19125535      0x123D51F       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19126371      0x123D863       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19127311      0x123DC0F       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19128211      0x123DF93       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19129183      0x123E35F       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19130043      0x123E6BB       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19131011      0x123EA83       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19131943      0x123EE27       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19132815      0x123F18F       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19133751      0x123F537       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19134587      0x123F87B       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19135467      0x123FBEB       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19140039      0x1240DC7       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19140799      0x12410BF       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19141559      0x12413B7       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19142999      0x1241957       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19143879      0x1241CC7       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19144751      0x124202F       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19146019      0x1242523       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19146859      0x124286B       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19147735      0x1242BD7       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19148607      0x1242F3F       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19149471      0x124329F       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19150371      0x1243623       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19151867      0x1243BFB       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19152791      0x1243F97       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19153683      0x1244313       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19154543      0x124466F       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19155419      0x12449DB       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19156291      0x1244D43       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19157215      0x12450DF       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19158063      0x124542F       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19158999      0x12457D7       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19160611      0x1245E23       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19161599      0x12461FF       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19162571      0x12465CB       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19163555      0x12469A3       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19164515      0x1246D63       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19165395      0x12470D3       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19166291      0x1247453       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19167167      0x12477BF       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19168047      0x1247B2F       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19168907      0x1247E8B       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19169831      0x1248227       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19170703      0x124858F       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19171579      0x12488FB       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19172551      0x1248CC7       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19173447      0x1249047       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19174419      0x1249413       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19175315      0x1249793       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19176299      0x1249B6B       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19177195      0x1249EEB       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19178107      0x124A27B       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19178963      0x124A5D3       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19179883      0x124A96B       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19180871      0x124AD47       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19181839      0x124B10F       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19182819      0x124B4E3       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19183767      0x124B897       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19184643      0x124BC03       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19185535      0x124BF7F       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19186411      0x124C2EB       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19187291      0x124C65B       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19188159      0x124C9BF       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19189943      0x124D0B7       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19190799      0x124D40F       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19191559      0x124D707       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19192871      0x124DC27       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19193707      0x124DF6B       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19194567      0x124E2C7       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19195395      0x124E603       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19196319      0x124E99F       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19197475      0x124EE23       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19198355      0x124F193       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19199211      0x124F4EB       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19201407      0x124FD7F       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19202227      0x12500B3       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19203095      0x1250417       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19203963      0x125077B       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19204795      0x1250ABB       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19205627      0x1250DFB       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19206475      0x125114B       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19207311      0x125148F       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19208215      0x1251817       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19209143      0x1251BB7       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19209995      0x1251F0B       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19210851      0x1252263       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19211759      0x12525EF       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19212647      0x1252967       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19213491      0x1252CB3       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19214359      0x1253017       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19215299      0x12533C3       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19216283      0x125379B       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19217275      0x1253B7B       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19218259      0x1253F53       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19219251      0x1254333       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19220227      0x1254703       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19221203      0x1254AD3       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19222831      0x125512F       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19223727      0x12554AF       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19224627      0x1255833       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19225547      0x1255BCB       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19226719      0x125605F       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19227967      0x125653F       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19228859      0x12568BB       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19229979      0x1256D1B       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19230915      0x12570C3       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19231807      0x125743F       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19232783      0x125780F       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19233671      0x1257B87       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19234523      0x1257EDB       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19235391      0x125823F       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19236243      0x1258593       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19237307      0x12589BB       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19238403      0x1258E03       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19239271      0x1259167       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19240199      0x1259507       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19241115      0x125989B       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19242071      0x1259C57       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19242999      0x1259FF7       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19244123      0x125A45B       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19245759      0x125AABF       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19246635      0x125AE2B       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19247571      0x125B1D3       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19248495      0x125B56F       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19249439      0x125B91F       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19250387      0x125BCD3       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19251231      0x125C01F       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19252043      0x125C34B       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19252931      0x125C6C3       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19253815      0x125CA37       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19254911      0x125CE7F       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19255787      0x125D1EB       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19256695      0x125D577       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19257671      0x125D947       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19258579      0x125DCD3       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19259535      0x125E08F       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19260423      0x125E407       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19261391      0x125E7CF       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19262271      0x125EB3F       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19263243      0x125EF0B       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19264079      0x125F24F       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19264931      0x125F5A3       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19265795      0x125F903       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19266759      0x125FCC7       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19267979      0x126018B       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19268859      0x12604FB       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19269787      0x126089B       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19270671      0x1260C0F       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19271599      0x1260FAF       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19272503      0x1261337       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19273455      0x12616EF       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19274331      0x1261A5B       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19275211      0x1261DCB       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19276155      0x126217B       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19277027      0x12624E3       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19277879      0x1262837       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19278791      0x1262BC7       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19279551      0x1262EBF       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19280947      0x1263433       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19281807      0x126378F       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19282723      0x1263B23       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19283775      0x1263F3F       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19284699      0x12642DB       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
19285547      0x126462B       Copyright string: "copyright notice above dose not evidence any actual or intended"
20018400      0x13174E0       VxWorks WIND kernel version "2.11"
20052944      0x131FBD0       CRC32 polynomial table, big endian
```

Comment: Have you tried to google this? [This](https://askubuntu.com/q/85977/129094) is my first hit for "mount filesystem in file".

Comment: yes I did and I get this error "sudo mount -o loop Lzma1.lzma q/
mount: /home/rambo/Desktop/Router-research/Dlink/Routers/DES3200/extracted/q: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop2, missing codepage or helper program, or other error"

Comment: `Lzma1.lzma` is most likely LZMA-compressed, you have to decompress it first. Why do you think there are filesystems inside? Can you show relevant command outputs? Please [edit] the question and include all relevant information.

Comment: yes ofcourse... following is the output of binwalk for Lzma1   DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
15148890      0xE7275A        eCos RTOS string reference: "ECOS"
15283022      0xE9334E        eCos RTOS string reference: "ECOS"
15298264      0xE96ED8        eCos RTOS string reference: "ECOS"
15298321      0xE96F11        eCos RTOS string reference: "ECOS" etc etc which wont come inside a comment.

Comment: Please [edit] the question as I suggested, the above is completely unreadable.

Comment: and I did ... but still no response @gronostaj